# jquery append only 2 times how it works?

Tags: jquery

Hi all I have this scripts and I want to append happen only 2 times

```
$(".upload_add").click(function(){
$("#film_upload_side")
.append('<div class="class">content</div>');
});
```

Comment: Use counter and check how much div's you have already appended.

Comment: Write it inside a for loop with condition _less than_ or _equal to_ 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = 0;

$(".upload_add").click(function(){
a ++;
if (a <=6)
$("#film_upload_side")
.append('<div class="class">content</div>');
});
```